# What is the difference between build and Clean&Rebuild in VS2019

Tags: build, uwp, visual-studio-2019

While build the solution in VS2019 for a UWP project, Its got the build failed with the following error message, 
"Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.'"

Once get clean and Rebuild the solution, then the build gets successed.

Is there any difference between build and clean&Rebuild in the VS2019?

Answer (score 1):

**Build**

`Build` will generate any assemblies that have changed files and will not build if the files have not changed.

At the same time, during our creation of UWP, Visual Studio will generate some intermediate files, and the build operation will not delete them.

**Rebuild**

In contrast to `Build`, `Rebuild` deletes all generated assemblies, intermediate files, etc. and compiles the entire project from scratch.

---

The problem you encountered may be in the process of writing the code, the application version is modified, or other reasons cause the old assembly to fail, and you need to rebuild the project to compile normally.